# how to filter a wpf gridview that is filled with MySqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, filter, fill

this is how my data gridview is filled:

```
using (MySqlDataAdapter a = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    a.FillAsync(dt);
    dataGridView1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

}
```

now i used to filter my data-grid view in winforms this way:

```
string rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", "full name", pattern);
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

here is the wpf version of it which does not work

```
string rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", "full name", pattern);
((DataView)dataGridView1.ItemsSource).ToTable().DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

the above **wpf version code** runs ok but it **doesn't filter** the gridview instead it passes over it (the code ) like nothing happened?

at last How can i filter my wpf datagridview?

P.S: i am both new and not good when it comes to xaml and that's why i prefer c# code solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank God ... i just found the solution!!!

```
string rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", "full name", pattern);
((DataView)dataGridView1.ItemsSource).RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

i was using the **DefaultView.RowFilter** which **does not work** when instead i should've used the **DataView.RowFilter** (**Works** like charm).

and for anyone new on row filtering here is what i consider [row filter cheat sheet](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/).